# LG phone starts on recovery mode automatically

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, lg

My LG phone was rooted and TWRP was installed on it. I try to update my Android version using the LG software update center, and after downloading updates, I tap on install. But after my phone restarts to install updates, it goes into recovery mode, and after rebooting the system again, it automatically goes to recovery mode.

I restore my system backup to fix it, but it doesn't make it better.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you root your phone or installs TWRP you give up on Android updates. Those two things don't work together because when you root you change the system image, and to install updates you need to have stock recovery too. So download latest firmware and flash it on your device (TWRP and root will be lost).

Comment: Thanks but please tell me which flash tool i have to use?(because my phone always in recovery mode) is lg flash tool still working? guide me more please

Comment: @H Rajabi  As far as I can remember you can use LG bridge or LG up to flash it. What is exact model of your phone?